In latex how to add the current folder to graphicspath if graphicspath is used
I am trying to compile a simple latex file.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.05cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{grfext}

\graphicspath{{./figures/}}
% \graphicspath{{./}{./figures/}}

% \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.eps}
% \AtBeginDocument{%
%   \PrependGraphicsExtensions*{
%     .mps,.MPS,.pdf,.PDF,.eps,.EPS,.ps,.PS,
%     .png,.PNG,.jpg,.jpeg,.JPG,.JPEG,
%   }%
%   %\PrintGraphicsExtensions % see .log file
% }

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{quadrant}
\end{document}

Earlier I think I didn't need to add the current folder to the graphicspath. But now it doesn't seem to work. How do I add the current folder to \graphicspath, since \graphicspath{{./}{./figures/}} doesn't seem to work (unless I add the extension .pdf in the tex file, i.e. quadrant.pdf, which I don't want to)?
My current pdflatex version (from the log file) is as follows:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded    
format=pdflatex 2024.3.20)


Never mind. I just figured out the problem. The figures folder also had a file called quadrant.tex and as such it was creating the problem. Once I renamed the tex quadrant.tex to quadrant2.tex everything was fine. I didn't even need to add the parent folder to the \graphicspath
